# How to list all the activities in a specific google domain?

Tags: google-plus

Any ideas on how can I list all the activities in my domain by using the new google+ domain's API in java?

The Developers' Live video shows at 4:00 minute mark that you can do something like this:

```
Plus.Activities.List listActivities = plus.activities().list("me", "domain");
```

The Link for this code is [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/reading).

But when I actually run the same line of code it shows me the following error.

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "collection",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid string value: 'domain'. Allowed values: [user]",
    "reason" : "invalidParameter"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid string value: 'domain'. Allowed values: [user]"
}
```

The error makes sense as in the [activities.list documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/list) it says that "user" is the only acceptable value for collection and not "domain."

So what should I do about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the only available way is to list posts by the currently logged user. You have to use user delegation (with service accounts) and loop over all users in the domain in order to get all published activities.

You can use the `updated` field on the response to check if there is anything new in a user's list of activities.

This line of thought applies to the whole Domains API: every operation is done **on behalf of a user**, there is no "admin" account with superpowers. This can be a limitation when acting on a big number of users, as you are forced to authenticate for each one in turn (if someone has an idea on how to achieve this in a more efficient way, please share!)

Comment: The code snippet was incorrect and has been updated. Indeed, every operation must be done on behalf of a user. To clarify, domain-wide delegation is a means by which you can authenticate an app on behalf of every user within your domain, so that each user does not need to log in. But, to use the authentication, you must specify the account you wish to act on behalf of, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation sais, only "public" is allowed:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

However even using the code provided in the example in the API doc, after going through successful authentication I get 0 activities.

```
 /** List the public activities for the authenticated user. */
  private static void listActivities() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Listing My Activities");
    // Fetch the first page of activities
    Plus.Activities.List listActivities = plus.activities().list("me", "public");
    listActivities.setMaxResults(100L);
    // Pro tip: Use partial responses to improve response time considerably
    listActivities.setFields("nextPageToken,items(id,url,object/content)");

    ActivityFeed activityFeed = listActivities.execute();
    // Unwrap the request and extract the pieces we want
    List<Activity> activities = activityFeed.getItems();
    System.out.println("Number of activities: " + activities.size());
    // Loop through until we arrive at an empty page
    while (activities != null) {
      for (Activity activity : activities) {
        System.out.println("ID " + activity.getId() + " Content: " +
                activity.getObject().getContent());
      }

      // We will know we are on the last page when the next page token is null.
      // If this is the case, break.
      if (activityFeed.getNextPageToken() == null) {
        break;
      }

     // Prepare to request the next page of activities
      listActivities.setPageToken(activityFeed.getNextPageToken());

      // Execute and process the next page request
      activityFeed = listActivities.execute();
      activities = activityFeed.getItems();
    }
}
```

Anybody know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

when you use Google+ API you must use "public" but when you use Google+ Domains API you must use "user" parameter value.